# Render out a tree

Tags: javascript

I need to render out flat data with relations into an html tree structure in javascript. I need to do it without help from any libraries. The data itself is flat:

```
[
{id : 1, title : one, parent : null},
{id : 2, title : two, parent : 1},
{id : 3, title : three, parent : 2},
{id : 4, title : four, parent : null},
{id : 5, title : five, parent : 4},
{id : 6, title : six, parent : 4},
{id : 7, title : seven, parent : 6},
{id : 8, title : eight, parent : 7},
{id : 9, title : nine, parent : 8}
]
```

And this is the desired result:

```
<div>one
  <div>two
    <div>three</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>four
  <div>five</div>
  <div>six
    <div>seven
      <div>eight
        <div>nine
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The depth of the data is arbitrary (i.e. it can be one or a hundred levels deep depending on the data).

I've been looking around for an answer, but most of them point to libraries or use data that itself is nested (which in most cases only would push the problem of nesting over to the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive function to turn an array of objects (with your structure) into an `html` string, representing a hierarchy of `div` tags.

```
function menuTree(nodes, parentId) {
    return nodes.reduce(function(html, node) {
        return html + (node.parent === parentId
            ? '\n<div>' + node.title + menuTree(nodes, node.id) + '</div>'
            : '');
    }, '');
}
```

You call it like this:

```
var nodes = [
    {"id": 1, "title": "one",   "parent": null},
    {"id": 2, "title": "two",   "parent": 1},
    {"id": 3, "title": "three", "parent": 2},
    {"id": 4, "title": "four",  "parent": null},
    {"id": 5, "title": "five",  "parent": 4},
    {"id": 6, "title": "six",   "parent": 4},
    {"id": 7, "title": "seven", "parent": 6},
    {"id": 8, "title": "eight", "parent": 7},
    {"id": 9, "title": "nine",  "parent": 8}
];
var html = menuTree(nodes, null);
console.log(html);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arpjvdoo/) that demonstrates the above interactively. This fiddle allows you to change the `json` description and reproduce the `div` tree accordingly. By using some basic `css` the `div` tree is rendered with indentation.

Answer (score 1):

An iterative way with cost O(n) would be

```js
function makeTree(data) {
  var elements = Array(data.length + 1),
      proto = document.createElement('div');
  for(var i=0; i<=data.length; ++i)
    elements[i] = proto.cloneNode(false);
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
    var elem = elements[data[i].id];
    elements[+data[i].parent].appendChild(elem);
    elem.insertBefore(
      document.createTextNode(data[i].title),
      elem.firstChild
    );
  }
  return elements[0];
}
```

```js
var data = [
  {id : 9, title : "nine", parent : 8},
  {id : 1, title : "one", parent : null},
  {id : 2, title : "two", parent : 1},
  {id : 3, title : "three", parent : 2},
  {id : 4, title : "four", parent : null},
  {id : 5, title : "five", parent : 4},
  {id : 6, title : "six", parent : 4},
  {id : 7, title : "seven", parent : 6},
  {id : 8, title : "eight", parent : 7}
];
function makeTree(data) {
  var elements = Array(data.length + 1),
      proto = document.createElement('div');
  for(var i=0; i<=data.length; ++i)
    elements[i] = proto.cloneNode(false);
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
    var elem = elements[data[i].id];
    elements[+data[i].parent].appendChild(elem);
    elem.insertBefore(
      document.createTextNode(data[i].title),
      elem.firstChild
    );
  }
  return elements[0];
}
document.body.appendChild(makeTree(data));
```

```css
div {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The code above will work even if you reference an element as a parent before defining its data. However, it assumes the IDs are consecutive integers from 1 to n. If they can be sparse or strings, then use an object instead of an array. In average it will also be O(n).

```js
var data = [
  {id : "id9", title : "nine", parent : "id8"},
  {id : "id1", title : "one", parent : null},
  {id : "id2", title : "two", parent : "id1"},
  {id : "id3", title : "three", parent : "id2"},
  {id : "id4", title : "four", parent : null},
  {id : "id5", title : "five", parent : "id4"},
  {id : "id6", title : "six", parent : "id4"},
  {id : "id7", title : "seven", parent : "id6"},
  {id : "id8", title : "eight", parent : "id7"}
];
function makeTree(data) {
  function getEl(id) {
    if(id === null) return wrapper;
    return elements[id] = elements[id] || wrapper.cloneNode(false);
  }
  var elements = {},
      wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
    var el = getEl(data[i].id);
    getEl(data[i].parent).appendChild(el);
    el.insertBefore(
      document.createTextNode(data[i].title),
      el.firstChild
    );
  }
  return wrapper;
}
document.body.appendChild(makeTree(data));
```

```css
div {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP's question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but trincot is right. I wanted to render the data out into html, not the other way around. Please tell me if you think there is anything I could do to make the question clearer for future referrers.

Comment: @tricot You are right, I have fixed the answer with a O(n) iterative approach which beats your O(n^2) ;)